# Using Angular 7.x with Protractor 6 (beta)

Tags: angular, selenium-webdriver, protractor, angular-cli

Was anyone able, yet, to execute `Angular CLI` `7.x` E2E tests using `Protractor 6 (beta)`? Due to issues described at https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/4294, I was looking forward to give `selenium-webdriver@4.0.0-alpha.1` a try, but it did not seem to be as straightforward and ran into issues that the `webdriver-manager` could not be found.

A `Protractor` beta release was cut here:

https://github.com/angular/protractor/commit/205c4d88ace8851b8fa71a75c5d66249c9a63c3b

**Update (working now)**

I believe I got it. Steps to make it work:

Using Node `10.15.0 LTS` on `Mac OS X 10.13.6`:

```sh
$ node -v
v10.15.0
```

Using Angular CLI `7.2.1`.

```sh
$ ng version

     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 7.2.1
Node: 10.15.0
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 7.2.0
...
```

Create a simple app:

`$ ng new ng72 --routing=true --style=scss`

Update `package.json`:

- `"jasmine-core": "^3.3.0",`
- `"protractor": "6.0.0-beta"`

Update the test for `await/async`:

```js
    import { AppPage } from './app.po';

    describe('workspace-project App', () => {
      let page: AppPage;

      beforeEach(() => {
        page = new AppPage();
      });

      it('should display welcome message', async() => {
        await page.navigateTo();
        await expect(await page.getTitleText()).toEqual('Welcome to ng72!');
      });
    });
```

Then execute:

- `$ npm install`
- `$ ./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update`
- `$ npm rebuild node-sass`
- `$ ng e2e --no-webdriver-update`

Google (`Version 72.0.3626.53`) will start up and the test is executing successfully.

As a side-note. If you don't do `await page.getTitleText()`, then the test 
 fails with a rather obscure **NoSuchSessionError: invalid session id**:

```sh
**************************************************
*                    Failures                    *
**************************************************

1) workspace-project App should display welcome message
  - Expected ElementFinder({ browser_: ProtractorBrowser({ execute: Function, setFileDetector: Function, getExecutor: Function, getSession: Function, getCapabilities: Function, quit: Function, actions: Function, executeScript: Function, executeAsyncScript: Function, wait: Function, sleep: Function, getWindowHandle: Function, getAllWindowHandles: Function, getPageSource: Function, close: Function, getCurrentUrl: Function, getTitle: Function, findElementInternal_: Function, findElementsInternal_: Function, takeScreenshot: Function, manage: Function, switchTo: Function, driver: Driver({ session_: [object Promise], executor_: Executor({ w3c: false, customCommands_: Map( [ 'launchApp', Object({ method: 'POST', path: '/session/:sessionId/chromium/launch_app' }) ], [ 'getNetworkConditions', Object({ method: 'GET', path: '/session/:sessionId/chromium/network_conditions' }) ], [ 'setNetworkConditions', Object({ method: 'POST', path: '/session/:sessionId/chromium/network_conditions' }) ], [ 'sendDevTools ... to equal 'Welcome to ng72!'.

Executed 1 of 1 spec (1 FAILED) in 0.484 sec.
Randomized with seed 13684.
/Users/dev/ng72/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:3190
        throw arguments[0];
        ^

NoSuchSessionError: invalid session id
  (Driver info: chromedriver=72.0.3626.7 (efcef9a3ecda02b2132af215116a03852d08b9cb),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.6 x86_64)
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Protractor 6.0.0-beta does not work with angular-cli

Thank you for being on the bleeding edge (and trying out my release)! Hopefully it is mostly working other than this issue. Unfortunately, the angular-cli and the new version (6.0.0-beta) of Protractor will not work together. The story for this will improve once Protractor is officially released and the angular-cli uses it.

For now the recommended path is if you want to use the 6 beta, to separate it (your tests) from the angular-cli project.

#### When `page.getTitleText()` is not awaited

Your error with `page.getTitleText()` might have something to do with when the promise eventually gets resolved, the browser session was closed by Protractor (this is probably not the best error message). Also you just need to do a `expect(await page.getTitleText()).toEqual('Welcome to ng72!');`, you do need an `await` in front of the `expect`.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! Tried to use Protractor stand-alone. One issue I run into is the order of test-cases. By default tests are now executed in random order:

```bash
Randomized with seed 78491
Started
Jasmine started
```
I have a hard time to override that:

```json
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
      random: false,
      ...
 }

```

I saw some pointers that the underlying Jasmine configuration changed in `3.3.0`. Do I miss something or is this still something outstanding?

Comment: Looks like `jasmine.getEnv().randomizeTests(false);` does the trick.

Comment: Hmm... Looks like this should happen by default.